# Using JPA implementations in desktop applications?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I'm generally a web developer so I'm used to ORM-style abstraction, but find myself working on a desktop app at the moment.

I've read a few warnings about using Hibernate in desktop applications because of slow startup time, and [blog posts](http://blog.pursuit.be/2008/04/jpa-not-ready-for-desktop-applications.html) about JPA implementations not being ready for the desktop.

I'm hoping that standard practice for modern J2SE desktop apps isn't just to store the objects in ArrayLists, and that there is some sort of persistence layer that can help out....

Comment: What has "desktop" or "download size" got to do with JPA implementations not being usable in an app ? you need an EMF, so thats maybe a second to start it, but that can easily be swallowed in app startup time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog you are referring to talks about the sizes, not startup times.

If you are writing a real desktop application, you shouldn't worry about the size or bootstrap time implications of adding another API. Just look at the size of the installs and start times of Eclipse (Java) or Microsoft Word (native).

Although I can see how the startup time penalty might be an issue for a small command line utility.

Comment: Furthermore the blog title is wrong.  The argument the author is making is that JPA isn't ready for web-deployed desktop applications (e.g. WebStart).  Furthermore, that was in 2008 and things could have changed.

Datanucleus has several options for fine-tuning the startup time if it really is something you're worried about.  You can explicitly list classes so it doesn't have to scan for them.  You can disable auto-start so metadata is loaded lazily, etc.  Haven't done it myself so I don't know how fast it gets but its worth looking into.

Comment: Eclipse start times are terrible :) I found this shortly after posting, NetBeans defaults to EclipseLink for persistence: http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html#creating-app